# MySQL - Select multiple rows from one table whose IDs are stored in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm confused using a `JOIN` - Statement to select my data from my MySQL Database.
Here is how the tables look like:

```
Table "Users"
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Name  | Password |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | Mike  | test     |
| 2  | Tony  | test1    |
| 3  | Frank | test2    |
+----+-------+----------+

Table "Games"
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| ID | Player1ID | Player2ID | ScoreP1 | ScoreP2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1  |         1 |         2 |       5 |       2 |
| 2  |         3 |         1 |       2 |       1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to `SELECT * FROM GAMES WHERE Player1ID=1 or Player2ID=1` plus the names of the users and not just their IDs. 
Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the `users` table twice with different alias names for them to distinguish them

```
select g.*, u1.name as player1, u2.name as player2
from games g
join users u1 on u1.id = g.player1id
join users u2 on u2.id = g.player2id
```

Comment: I will try that... thanks! Can you check my EDIT. What if want to `SELECT...WHERE` ? thanks

Comment: Just add the `where` clause to the end of this query